# Ruby doesn't raise correct exception

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, tdd

I'm trying to raise 2 exceptions when one of my variables is bigger than 13 or less than 1
also I want to raise exception if the type of my **card** is not one of the defined one.
this is my code :

```
require "../lib/suit"
class Card
    attr_reader :suit,:number
 def initialize(suit,number)
     raise "CardNumberNotValid" if 1>number>13
     raise "SuitNotValid" if suit!=Suit::CLUB or suit!=Suit::HEART or suit!=Suit::DIAMOND or suit!=Suit::SPADE
     @suit=suit
     @number=number
 end
end
```

and this is my test:

```
require "rspec"
require "../lib/suit"
require "../lib/card"

describe Card do

  it "should check if card number is between 1 and 13" do
    expect{Card.new(Suit::CLUB,14)}.to raise_error("CardNumberNotValid")
  end
end
```

The result is below :

> Failures:
>
> 1) Card should check if card number is between 1 and 13
>        Failure/Error: expect{Card.new(Suit::CLUB,14)}.to raise_error("CardNumberNotValid")
>          expected Exception with "CardNumberNotValid", got #' for false:FalseClass>
>        # ./card_spec.rb:8
>
> Finished in 0.00064 seconds 1 example, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./card_spec.rb:7 # Card should check if card number is between 1
>   and 13

can you please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1>number>13
```

Does not work in Ruby. Use something like:

```
number.between?(1, 13)
```

Comment: Thanks , I didn't notice that :) I'm new to Ruby

Answer (score 0):

If you raise an error in ruby without a type:

```
raise "My pink pig"
```

ruby is going to raise a RuntimeError with "My pink pig" as a message (assuming that you aren't already processing an error, in which case the new error will have the same type).

You should probably be expecting your error differently:

```
expect{Card.new(Suit::CLUB,14)}.to raise_error(RuntimeError, "CardNumberNotValid")
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not working same error got #<NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for false:FalseClass>